# What is the shortest bash glob pattern/expression to match all file/dir names (including those beginning with a dot, but excluding . and ..)

Tags: bash, glob, dotfiles

I have `extglob` set and `dotglob` unset.

`.*` also yields `.` and `..`, which is usually undesirable with `mv` or `cp`, so I don't want those included.

I played around a bit and found that `*(?(.)+([^.]))` and `$(ls -A)` give the desired result, but I think there should be an easier way...

I am looking for a pattern to be used at the prompt, not within a script.

Comment: `$(ls -A)` is dangerously buggy; don't ever use it. (Keep in mind that filenames can have spaces, and newlines, and wildcard characters).

Comment: Note also that `.` and `..` *are valid filesystem objects*; when you ask the OS to list entries in the current directory, they're things it returned, not magic aliases bash made up, so it's generally appropriate for something that's returning OS-provided results to you to include them absent contrary instruction.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: $(ls -A): Yes, thank you, I didn't take this into account. Concerning `.` and `..`: I know, I just mentioned this because I was naive and did `cp .* <dest>`, which of course copied the contents of the parent directory too.

Comment: I didn't know `ls -A`  was considered buggy, anyhow good question, and good answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
unset GLOBIGNORE  # empty-by-default, but let's make sure
shopt -s dotglob  # disable special handling for "hidden" files

# ...and with the above items both done:
files=( * )       # just an example use of a glob
```

...sets the array `files` to contain all objects in the current directory except `.` and `..`; any other use of `*` would behave similarly.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but that's not an expression, that's a script ;) I could make an expression out of this: `$(unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -s dotglob; echo *)`, but that one would be even longer than my approach (`*(?(.)+([^.]))`)...

Comment: Sure. I don't consider terseness a desirable attribute in shell -- due to the legacy of decades of backwards compatibility with poorly-thought-through predecessors and standards, the short thing is usually *wrong* in some subtle way. Better to suck it up and deal with code that goes to lengths to be explicit in service of correctness, or rewrite in a different language.

Comment: That said, the `unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -s dotglob` can happen *just once* at the top of your script, making the glob expression itself just `*`. (`$(unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -s dotglob; echo *)` is buggy for the same reasons as `ls -A`, btw, plus some additional reasons all its own -- see [Stephane's excellent answer on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) re: why `echo` is unreliable even when you know your shell will be bash).

Comment: @Christoph, ...keep in mind that SO's scope is narrowed to "practical" questions. Terseness-above-all-else is, in light of the correctness tradeoffs, often *impractical* -- that being part of why we banished code golf games to [codegolf.se] rather than permitting them here.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you wanted to correctly run that in a subshell, you'd want something more like: `readarray -t files < <(unset GLOBIGNORE; shopt -s dotglob nullglob; set -- *; (( $# )) && printf '%s\0' "$@")` to populate `"${files[@]}"` for later expansion.

Comment: I fully agree with you when writing a script, but I was looking for a handy expression to be used at the prompt. But if such an expression doesn't exist, I will use your script and give it a handy name.

Comment: Ah. SO is only for questions about *writing software*. If you're looking for handy CLI expressions, try [unix.se].